# class not found and null object reference exception out of nowhere

Tags: android

I have now completed all the scripting and designing with no compile time error but out of no where this run time error comes in and my app flashes away and do not get launched.
I have got all the files that it requires and everything done,
Please suggest now,

This is my MainActivity.java code thats probably throwing these exceptions

```
package com.example.dell.demologin;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;

import activity.LoginActivity;
import helper.SQLiteHandler;
import helper.SessionManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtName;
private TextView txtEmail;
private Button btnLogout;
private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);


    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String email = user.get("email");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtEmail.setText(email);

    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
 * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
 * */
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    db.deleteUsers();

    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

}
```

This is my logcat,

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.dell.demologin, PID: 15578
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dell.demologin.AppController
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:601)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4757)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dell.demologin.AppController
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:220)
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239)
      at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:187)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1001)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:985)
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:586)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4757) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dell.demologin.AppController
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209)
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
      at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:187) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1001) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:985) 
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:586) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4757) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dell.demologin.AppController" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.dell.demologin-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.dell.demologin-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285) 
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.createRealApplication(BootstrapApplication.java:209) 
      at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.attachBaseContext(BootstrapApplication.java:239) 
      at android.app.Application.attach(Application.java:187) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1001) 
      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:985) 
      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:586) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4757) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:159) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1445) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.dell.demologin.AppController" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_2f85958e3577c0887206665b958d529f2917b10d-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-mysql-connector-java_910883ba1d0637ad761451367a22e76261a44141-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jtds_dd6bef0a517729fc55f6897f784dfc3379233a03-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.dell.demologin/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_acbefc0422230ccc1164ab
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.Application.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:96)
      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15578 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: _java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dell.demologin.AppController_ Does the class exist in this package?

Comment: This is most likely a problem with your xml @KNeerajLal

Comment: @KNeerajLal, it is there in my package

Comment: @TeddyWilson I have 3 xmls one for login page, one for registration and one for the dashboard, so which one u think it is ?

Comment: @manvendradubey Please post your xml for activity_register, because that's where the error is occurring, right?

Answer (score 0):

Known bug in the Google Play store upgrade process, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56296